# Can we view the full dataset and not the distinct on BO Web Intelligence?

Tags: business-objects, infoview

When running a query on BO Web Intelligence (BO 3.1 XI) , although the full dataset is fetched, Web Intelligence only shows the distinct values by default, which can cause confusion.

Is there any option to view the full dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two settings that are applicable.  The first is in the Query Panel Properties: `Retrieve Duplicate Rows`; this should be checked (it is by default).

The second setting is in the report block properties.  Right-click on the border around the report block and click `Format`.  This will bring up the Properties panel for the report block.  Under the "Display" header you should see a setting for `Avoid duplicate row aggregation` (which is off by default).  Click it, and you should see your duplicate rows.